# ¿Cómo pasar el value y el index de una lista con angularjs llamando una funcion desde onchange?

Tags: angularjs

Estoy trabajando con angularjs, necesito pasar 2 parámetros a una función en el js, lo estoy haciendo de esta forma y no me funciona:

```
onchange="Myfunction(this,$index)"
```

cuando paso el solo el this a la funcion le llega el value seleccionado, pero no me pasa el index. Como lo puedo hacer?

Esta es mi función:

function Myfunction(selectObject,idx)
{

```
    var valortipificacion=selectObject.value;


    if(valortipificacion=="Ok")
    {
        acepta[idx].checked=true;
    } 
    else
    {
        acepta[idx].checked=false; 

    }
```

}

Este es el HTML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El **$index** viene de un repeat? estaría bien que mostraras como esta compuesta tu función.

Comment: @HectorEcheverri Agrega mas contenido por favor.

Comment: @Roberto Munguia, TheVicious: Agregue la función que tengo en el JS

Comment: @HectorEcheverri Y el contenido del ng-repeat en el html? de donde sacas el $index?

Comment: @TheVicious lo acabo de agregar, gracias

Comment: Sigo sin ver el ng-repeat de donde sacas el $index...

Comment: @theVicious lo acabo de agregar en una imagen

Comment: @HectorEcheverri Es necesario hacerlo con onchange? por que no usas la directiva que te brinda angularJs **ng-change**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para AngularJS ese atributo *onchange* es un atributo más de html como *alt* ó *class* y no procesa lo que esta dentro como parte de AngularJS. La forma correcta de hacerlo sería usar *ng-change* y definir tu función 
*palanca()* dentro del controlador correspondiente.

Si por algún motivo lo necesitas si o sí por fuera de AngularJS como lo estas haciendo ahora, necesitas expresar el `$index`, es decír usarlo de la forma `{{ $index }}` cuando llamás a la función en el `onchange`.

Qudando algo asi:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in contingenciasTV track by $index">
  <td>
    <select ng-model="data.tipificacion" onchange="palanca(this, {{ $index }})">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Pero de nuevo, lo mejor sería que trabajes todo dentro del ecosistema de AngularJS usando *ng-change* como bien sugirieron antes.

Comment: lo hice dentro del controlador mejor como me lo sugerían y funcionó perfecto muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, si estás usando Angular JS, define las funciones dentro del controlador que estés usando.

La mejor forma de hacer lo que quieres es: asígnale al select una variable a través del atributo ng-model y así podrás obtener el elemento seleccionado de los options.

O si lo quieres hacer de forma menos bonita puedes quitar el "onchange" del select y a cada option colócale el evento "ng-click".

```
<select name="test1">
    <option value="item.id" ng-for="item in items" ng-click="tu_funcion(item.id, $index)">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Recuerda que Angular JS maneja los eventos colocando el prefijo "**ng-**"

- ng-click
- ng-change
- ng-blur
- ng-focus
- Entre otros... [Documentación](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp) [AngujarJS.org](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: lo hice dentro del controlador mejor como me lo sugerían y funcionó perfecto muchas gracias.